# Tornado asynchronous actions in custom decorator

Tags: python, tornado, decorator, coroutine

I am trying to build a caching decorator using redis and the tornadis library for my Tornado route handlers.
This is what I have so far:

```
def rediscache(route):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            result = yield redis.call("GET", "latest_info")
            print(result)
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Inside my route handler I am using it like so:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def initialize(self, db, redis):
        self.db = db
        self.quakes = self.db.quakes
        self.redis = redis

    @gen.coroutine
    @rediscache('route_is_here')
    def get(self):
        ''' ... handler logic here ... '''
```

Problem is that if I use my decorator, I stop seeing output to the web from my handler. If instead of ...

```
result = yield redis.call("GET", "latest_info")
```

I do ...

```
result = redis.call("GET", "latest_info")
```

Then I start to see output in my browser again but is this the proper way to do it? Is this still asynchronous? If not what is the propper way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: The `redis` library is not async. `tornadis`, however, is async. I don't see you using `tornadis` api anywhere in you code.

Comment: Sorry about that. "redis" is actually the name of the instance of tornadis.Client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapper in your decorator should be `gen.coroutine` if you want to `yield` coroutines:

```
def rediscache(route):
    def decorator(func):
        @tornado.gen.coroutine
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            result = yield redis.call("GET", "latest_info")
            print(result)
            if not result:
                new = yield func(*args, **kwargs)
                # save to
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

You need also change the order of decorators to:

```
@rediscache('route_is_here')
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    ''' ... handler logic here ... '''
```

**edit**

Explanation of the decorators order

```
@second
@first
def my_func():
    pass
```

is the same as

```
my_func = second(first(my_func))
```

So if you want to await (yield) your original `get` in decorator, you have to pass coroutine therefore it must be before `rediscache`.

More info about decorators - https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators

Comment: This worked! But could you please explain the logic of ordering the decorators?